# Trying to Get a Nested List of Users in a Group in Active PowerShell Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, multiple-domains, adgroup

I am trying to get a list of users in a group in an active directory. We have multiple domains. I want to run it from a central location that will poll each domain for each group. Also, I want it to display nested members as well.

Currently, I tried running this and it sort of worked when the machine was on the same domain as the domain I am polling. All members and nested members get displayed.

```
dsquery group -samid "group name" | dsget group -members -expand >c:\list.txt

"cn=username,ou=users,dc=domain1,dc=com"
```

But when I try to poll another domain there is no output.

```
dsquery group -samid "cn=group name,cn=users,dc=domain2,dc=com" | dsget group -members -expand >c:\list.txt

dsget failed: 'target object for this command' is  missing
```

Then if I try it without the same id I get an output.

```
dsquery group "cn=group name,cn=users,dc=domain2,dc=com" | dsget group -members -expand >c:\list.txt

"CN=username2,OU=users,DC=domain2,DC=com"
"CN=S-1-5-21,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=domain1,DC=com"
"cn=group name,ou=users,dc=domain2,dc=com"
```

So I get ids and it is not showing the nested members.

What can I do to get it to resolve the correct nested members and non-sids? Also, how would I go about making it poll multiple group names in multiple domains? Or should I just separate it all out and do one at a time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand your question is partly answered in [Listing users in ad group recursively with powershell script without CmdLets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8055338/608772)

But if you are working in W2K8R2 environement you can use Active-Directory module.

```
Import-Module activedirectory
Get-ADGroupMember groupName -Recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

In all cases you need to query your result from a GC "using Global Catalog option"

- IF you have the SamID as an input use below:

dsquery group -samid "group's SamID" **-gc** | dsget group -memberof -expand

- BUT IF you have the DistinguishedName as an input use below:

**dsget** group "group's Distinguished Name" **-gc** | dsget group -memberof -expand