# Running powershell script in different OS

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, admin, active-directory-group

I am trying to run the below mentioned command in Server 2012 & it's pulling users from Administrators user group. But in Server 2008R2, it's pulling from entire domain

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_GroupUser `
| where{$_.GroupComponent -like "*Administrators*"} `
|foreach { 
$data = $_.PartComponent -split "\," 
$data[1].Remove(0,5).Replace('"','') 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have guessed the issue is that win2008R2 has only PS 2.0.x.  I think this command `where{$_.GroupComponent -like "*Administrators*"}` is not available at that version so it queries the whole AD as a fallback (that is a guess).

From your description I did not understand if you want to query local server or domain so I will enter both (all are functional on win2008R2 (PS version 2.0.50727)):

To query local admins and

```
#get servers by AD OU
If (!(Get-Module ActiveDirectory)) {
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
}
function get-localadmins{
  [cmdletbinding()]
  Param(
  [string]$server
  )
  $group = get-wmiobject win32_group -ComputerName $server -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND SID='S-1-5-32-544'"
  $query = "GroupComponent = `"Win32_Group.Domain='$($group.domain)'`,Name='$($group.name)'`""
  $list = Get-WmiObject win32_groupuser -ComputerName $server -Filter $query
  $list | %{$_.PartComponent} | % {$_.substring($_.lastindexof("Domain=") + 7).replace("`",Name=`"","\")}
}

get-localadmins 'your_server_name'
```

If your goal is to query the whole AD then you can use:

On windows 2008 R2 SP1 it can produce an error: *System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: An error (1301) occurred while enumerating the groups.  The group's SID could not be resolved.*

You have to install a hotfix by Microsoft at: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2830145/sid-s-1-18-1-and-sid-s-1-18-2-cannot-be-mapped-on-windows-based-computers-in-a-domain-environment?wa=wsignin1.0%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0

The following code was taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8057025/6059896 (all credit to the author) - only changed the names of variables to fig my coding style.

```
$Recurse = $true

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$context_type = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
$group_principal_identity=[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($ct,'Administrators')
$group.GetMembers($Recurse)
```