# Inconsistent LDAP filter results

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap-query

I'm attempting to find out if a user is an indirect member of a specific AD group. This is done from a Delphi XE5 program but, for clarity, I have written (and tested) my samples in PowerShell.

Unfortunately, I receive completely inconsistent results from my LDAP queries: the same query will sometime work fine and, sometimes, return that the user isn't member of the given group.

Here is a (powershell) sample of what I'm attempting:

```
get-aduser -LDAPFilter "(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=egaa_app,OU=Applications,OU=access,OU=groups,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx)" -SearchBase "CN=usr-sgr,OU=expert1,OU=experts,OU=remoteusers,OU=users,OU=exogit,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx"
```

The above command should return the user `usr-sgr` object if it is directly or indirectly member of the AD group`egaa_app,OU=Applications,OU=access,OU=groups,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx`

Yet, when I run it once, I get an empty result. If I open the user in the AD MMC and update it somehow (in my case, I changed the user's "primary group" and then changed it back), the same query successfully returns the user object.

I have also attempted to use the "reverse" query (which check if a given group contains the user indirectly) and I witnessed the same behavior.

All this was done on a member server (Windows 2008 R2, patched), from within the same login session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can explain this to you.

**First** a small recall of the [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx) :

*The LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN is a matching rule OID that is designed to provide a method to look up the ancestry of an object. An example of such a query is one designed to check if a user "user1" is a member of group "group1". You would set the base to the user DN (cn=user1, cn=users, dc=x) and the scope to base, and use the following query.*

```
(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=Group1,OU=groupsOU,DC=x)
```

**Here** the attribute `memberof` is the one that is going to be searched in chain in each group object. Use the attribute editor from the 'user & computer active directory' MMC to follow this attribute :

[image: AD attribute Editor]

And then change the primary group, you will see that the new primary group disappear from the memberof attribute list, and the old one appear in the attribute.

**Conclusion**, the primary group is unsupported by the LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN.

**In any case be careful to setup the scope**  `-SearchScope` in PowerSell.

By the way, for me, the best tool to test this kind of filter is [LDIFDE.EXE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731033.aspx).

```
ldifde -f c:\temp\test.ldif -d "CN=Jean-Paul Blanc,OU=Interne,OU=Silogix,DC=silogix,DC=local" -r "(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=bidon,OU=Interne,OU=Silogix,DC=silogix,DC=local)" -p base
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot. However, I'm wondering what is the proper way of programatically check if a user belongs to the given group.

Comment: You've got the big picture, you just have to add the principal group. I gave some clues [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6441956/608772)